# Fullcalendar not showing last row EOD events in 'agendaDay' view

Tags: javascript, height, fullcalendar

I am using JQuery Fullcalendar (v2.6.1).

I created an event starting at 23:50 Today and end up at 02:00 am Tomorrow. But this event's title doesn't shown at Today's list. 
Content height is not adjusting with exact content.

```
$(document).on('pageshow','#index',function(e,data){    
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        editable: true,
        defaultView: 'agendaDay',
        events: [
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: new Date(y, m, d, 23, 50),
                allDay: false
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4yux1d8a/2/)

I want to fully show the marked event in the below image.[image]

Is it possible to show event details without breaking in today's list itself?

Comment: How do you expect to see it? you want to see the next day 1AM? I think you should go with a big Tooltip that shows the event details

Comment: Hello jeff, you got any solution?

Comment: @kim: I just reduced the 'top' css property of EOD events. So it will show inside the view.

Comment: Already did that. Can we display last slot time also? Like 12pm at the bottom of calendar. Means 10pm to 11pm and 11pm to 12pm.

Answer (score 0):

Use this format for start and end date.

```
  start: '2016-05-19T12:59:00', //start time
    end: '2016-05-20T10:00:00', //End time
```

And it will display the event in both days.

```
 defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
```

[image]

```
 defaultView: 'agendaDay',
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please check question once more

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).on('pageshow','#index',function(e,data){    
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        editable: true,
        defaultView: 'agendaDay',
        events: [
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: new Date(y, m, d, 23, 59),
                end: new Date(y, m, d+1, 14, 00),
                allDay: false
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

you have forgot to add endDate

Comment: i don't need to show it up to 2 pm.
Need to show event details in today's list too. Means, the last row must need event details

Comment: no it wont show any details because it don't any more space to show

Comment: Does it have any solution?

Comment: you want to bring next day agenda under today? its wont make any sense.